# How to change color of Font Awesome icon when menu is open?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, hamburger-menu

I made a "hamburger menu" via an input checked.

I would like to know what to target and what pseudo-element to use to change the font-awesome color or background when the menu is unfolded?
and if I can close this menu by clicking anywhere in the page?

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
}

#options li {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#options:hover {
  background-color: #254574;
  color: white;
}

.elem {
  list-style: none;
}

.show-modal {
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.show-modal:hover {
  background-color: grey;
}

.options {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #091f43;
  line-height: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.modifier-checkbox:checked~.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 4;
}

.elem {
  background-color: white;
}

.modifier-checkbox {
  opacity: 0;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: inherit;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  position: relative;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background: inherit;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2000px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    filter: blur(10px);
    margin: -20px;
  }
}

.header-card {
  padding: 0.8rem 1rem 0.5rem 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: $border;
}

.author {
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.94rem;
  color: #091f43;
}

.date {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #0000007e;
}

.content {
  font-size: 0.94rem;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1.15rem 1rem;
}

.img-card {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
  }
}

.flex-right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.fa-tag {
  margin-right: 0.4rem;
}

.tag {
  cursor: default;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.8rem;
  margin-right: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: 12px 12px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.112), -8px -8px 12px 0 rgba(149, 142, 216, 0.057);
  border-radius: 50px;
}

.likeBar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="header-card">
      <div class="column">
        <p class="author">auteur</p>
        <p class="date">date</p>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-right">
        <p v-if="tag" class="tag">
          <i class="icon-tag fas fa-tag"></i>tag
        </p>
        <div class="modifier-toggle">
          <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="modifier-checkbox-1" class="modifier-checkbox" />

          <label for="modifier-checkbox-1" class="modifier-toggle">
             <i class="show-modal fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
           </label>

          <ul class="options">
            <li class="elem">Modifier</li>
            <li class="elem">Supprimer</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

View on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5yf0sot/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- to change font-awesome color or background just try this

> CSS

```
.fas:hover {
  background-color: #000;
   color: #fff;
}
```

> JS

```
var ico = document.getElementsByClassName("fa-ico")[0]
ico.addEventListener('click', function () {
   this.style.color = "red"
})
```

- about closing the menu you can use `e.target`

> Example

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0]
container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
   if(e.target.className === "container") {
      this.style.display = "none";
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this
`.elem{background-color: red;padding:3px;text-align:center;color:green;}`

to change icon color use `color:<color-name>;` because is based font